# What is the best way to realise "join" with JS objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, meteor

I'm working with MeteorJS (aned MongoDB).

I have two collections :

- **events**, with idEvent
- **eventsType**, with idEventType (finite list of
  type of events)

The link between two collections must be realized with `idEvent == idEventType`.

The goal is to have an array of events, with eventstype object associed.

This following code is functionnal, but I find it horrible... What did you think about ?

```
  events() {
    // Type of event
    const eventsType = EventsType.find();
    const eventsTypeArray = [];
    eventsType.forEach((ev) => {
      eventsTypeArray[ev.idEventType] = ev;
    });

    // List of events
    const eventsList = Events.find();
    const eventsListArray = [];


    // Merge both data
    eventsList.forEach((ev) => {
      const evObj = ev;
      evObj.type = eventsTypeArray[ev.idEvent];
      eventsListArray.push(evObj);
    });

    return eventsListArray;
  }
```

Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `eventsList` and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to enrich the original item :

```
eventsListArray = eventsList.map(ev => Object.assign({type: eventsTypeArray[ev.idEvent]}, ev))
```

Test run :

```
originalArray = [{a:"1"}, {a:"2"}];
dataMap = { "1": 10, "2": 100 };
mappedArray = originalArray.map(i=>Object.assign({b:dataMap[i.a]}, i));
console.log(originalArray);
console.log(mappedArray);
```

Result :

```
[{a:"1"}, {a:"2"}] //original array left untouched
[{a:"1", b:10}, {a:"2", b:100}] // mappedArray contains the extra data
```

Comment: Perfect ! Many thanks.

Do you know if I can don't realise the indeaxge of dataMap ? :
`eventsType.forEach((ev) => {
      eventsTypeArray[ev.idEventType] = ev;
    });`

And realize a `find` directly for example ?

For have something like that : 
`eventsList.map(ev => Object.assign(ev, { type: eventsList.find(ev.idTruc) }));

eventsList being the return of Collection.find ()

Comment: @Aurélien Sure, the first parameter of `Object.assign` can be any object you want to use as a base for your result

Comment: I think we have not understood each other and I have difficulty expressing my worries in another language! Code speaks better than words ;-) https://jsfiddle.net/0aw8foLs/

Comment: Still a good anwser...! Thanks @Aaron. I have all I was expected for today. :p

Comment: @Aurélien Pas de quoi !

Comment: @Aurélien you should probably switch the order of the parameters of `Object.assign` though, right now you're modifying your original array because `Object.assign` modifies the object he's passed as first parameter.

Comment: Yes, I was made this change :)
The solution `find`doesn't work on my Object  (type : _Meteor.Collection.find() it's a cursor. It does not immediately access the database or return documents._) :'(

Comment: @Aurélien check out [their doc](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html), it looks like you could do something like `var myMessages = Messages.find({userId: Session.get('myUserId')}).fetch();`

Comment: everything is OK !
First message, 2x forEach, >10 LOC -- 
Last message, 0x forEach, <5 LOC  
:')

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar problem recently where I wanted to join data from two collections.

My solution was to create a new [local collection](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#local-collections) (this is a collection that lives on the client only).

**client:**

```
const LocalEvents = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

From there, instead of pushing your joined objects in to an array, you can join them and push the new objects in to the `LocalEvents` collection. This gives you the benefit of being able to query the new objects from the local minimongo collection. You'll need to make sure you clear the local collection when the template/component is destroyed. Also run a tracker function to empty the `LocalCollection` if your cursor changes.

```
Tracker.autorun((eventsType) => {
    LocalEvents.remove({});
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will use `.map` for the moment. :)